# Highcharts: Click to Highlight instead of Hide (= Always show non-selected)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When having *multiple series* in for example a Highcharts Line Chart, the default behaviour is to hide the series when clicking its legend item.

Is there a way to change/invert this behaviour so that:

- All lines are shown by default, but none is selected
- On selection, the selected lines gets a more prominent style but the other remain visible

In Highcharts' language, I think I'm looking for an option to style the non selected lines, something like:

```
states : {
   nonselected : {
       visible : true,
       opacity : 0.6
   }
}
```

Comment: this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/a366e89c/2/) can be usefull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide original series from legend with `showInLegend: false` create shadow series, which could be enabled by clicking in legend.

Live example:
https://jsfiddle.net/u8n1twdf/

```js
const origColors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors

const colors = origColors.map((color) => {
 const c = Highcharts.color(color)
  c.setOpacity(0.2)
  return c
})

const options = {
 chart: {
   events: {
     load () {
       const chart = this
       const series = this.series
       series.forEach((s, i) => {
         if (i < 3) s.update({ color: colors[i].get() })
          else s.update(Object.assign({ data: chart.options.series[i - 3].data, color: origColors[i - 3] }))
        })
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
   name: 's1',
   showInLegend: false,
    data: [...Array(5)].map(Math.random)
  }, {
   name: 's2',
   showInLegend: false,
    data: [...Array(5)].map(Math.random)
  }, {
   name: 's3',
   showInLegend: false,
    data: [...Array(5)].map(Math.random)
  }, { name: 's1', visible: false }, { name: 's2', visible: false }, { name: 's3', visible: false }]
}

const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', options)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```